# Why does WebRequest work with invalid URL?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to login to a site using `HTTPWebRequest` and it works. The problem is that it works even if I pass wrong credentials, or for that matter a wrong URL. No exception are thrown.

What should I do to get an exception in the following code?

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.1111.1.1111");
    ViewBag.Message = request.ContentLength;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "failed";
}
```

Or is there any other work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't actually making the request, just creating the class.  In order to make the request, you need to read the response.  You can also initiate the request by accessing the request stream.

```
//Create a new WebRequest Object to the mentioned URL.
WebRequest myWebRequest=WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");

// This will throw an exception if the request fails
WebResponse myWebResponse=myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't execute the request with this code, you have to add this :

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.1111.1.1111");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    ViewBag.Message = response.ContentLength;
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "failed";
}
```

After, with the exception, you can check [Status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_code) (401 Unauthorized, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to actually make the request not just create the class.

You can get the response with something like:

`HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you provide simply initialises the request object.  The parameters you are supplying to the request are considered valid and such there is no exception raised.

When you make a connection attempt errors may be raised.

See the [MSDN docs on `WebRequest.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) for more info on what exceptions and when they are raised.

Answer (score 0):

thankx people ... I researched on your answers and yes it worked ... i m able to login to facebook with some valid credentials... thats great!!! :) Below is my final code:-

```
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.facebook.com");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;



        string getUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
        string postData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", "", "");
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            ViewBag.Message = sourceCode;

        }
```

Ofcourse, there are many other things in the code apart from httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse... 
1) You have to run the httpwebrequest twice to first get the cookie collection and then use the same cookiecollection for actually logging in coz facebook sets certain cookies before login which it needs to fetch at the time of login ...
2) (this is the answer to my earlier question i.e how to check if the URL is working) so what u do is get the page contents in a string (in this case sourceCode) n then just search for a particular string which you think could possibly be there in the resulting page... like in this case i could be possibly redirected to the home page of the user on FB if i have successfully logged in. And that page could have stuff like User name or the Page Title would be "Facebook" ... n so on... So that how we check success of a URL with or without credentials....

Thats it... That simple thing took me like three days almost...!!! Ridiculous!

Comment: now i have another question thou... can i use the same code n do oauth authentication.... I mean i have a oauth URL given to me by someone and the username and password to facebook. now i tried replacing the strings in the code above but it wasnt of any use... i google'd, OFCOURSE... and it gives me all the other ways ... But i want to know if i cud use this same code with a few modifications ... you can suggest any URL's too so i can research there ... thanks in advance